# working with variadic arguments

Tags: clojure

I am playing around and trying to create my own reductions implementation, so far I have this which works with this test data:

```
((fn [func & args]
  (reduce (fn [acc item]
            (conj acc (func (last acc) item))
            )[(first args)] (first (rest args)))) * 2 [3 4 5]
```

What I don't like is how I am separating the args.

`(first args)` is what I would expect, i.e. 2 but `(rest args)` is `([3 4 5])` and so I am getting the remainder like this `(first (rest args))` which I do not like.

Am I missing some trick that makes it easier to work with variadic arguments?

Comment: Note you can use `second`: `(second [3 4 5])` is `4`.

Comment: You may find interesting [this blog](http://blog.jayfields.com/2010/07/clojure-destructuring.html).

Answer (score 4):

Variadic arguments are just about getting an unspecified number of arguments in a list, so all list/destructuring operations can be applied here.

For example:

```
(let [[fst & rst] a-list]
  ; fst is the first element
  ; rst is the rest
 )
```

This is more readable than:

```
(let [fst (first a-list)
      rst (rest a-list)]
  ; ...
 )
```

You can go further to get the first and second elements of a list (assuming it has >1 elements) in one line:

```
(let [fst snd & rst]
  ; ...
 )
```

I originally misread your question and thought you were trying to reimplement the `reduce` function. Here is a sample implementation I wrote for this answer which does’t use `first` or `rest`:

```
(defn myreduce
  ;; here we accept the form with no initial value
  ;; like in (myreduce * [2 3 4 5]), which is equivalent
  ;; to (myreduce * 2 [3 4 5]). Notice how we use destructuring
  ;; to get the first/rest of the list passed as a second
  ;; argument
  ([op [fst & rst]] (myreduce op fst rst))
  ;; we take an operator (function), accumulator and list of elements
  ([op acc els]
    ;; no elements? give the accumulator back
    (if (empty? els)
      acc
      ;; all the function's logic is in here
      ;; we're destructuring els to get its first (el) and rest (els)
      (let [[el & els] els]
        ;; then apply again the function on the same operator,
        ;; using (op acc el) as the new accumulator, and the
        ;; rest of the previous elements list as the new
        ;; elements list
        (recur op (op acc el) els)))))
```

I hope it helps you see how to work with list destructuring, which is probably what you want in your function. Here is a [relevant blog post](http://blog.jayfields.com/2010/07/clojure-destructuring.html) on this subject.

Answer (score 1):

*Tidying up your function.*

As @bfontaine commented, you can use `(second args)` instead of `(first (rest args))`:

```
(defn reductions [func & args]
  (reduce
    (fn [acc item] (conj acc (func (last acc) item)))
    [(first args)]
    (second args)))
```

This uses

- `func`
- `(first args)`
- `(second args)`

... but ignores the rest of `args`.

So we can use destructuring to name the first and second elements of `args` - `init` and `coll` seem suitable - giving

```
(defn reductions [func & [init coll & _]]
  (reduce
    (fn [acc item] (conj acc (func (last acc) item)))
    [init]
    coll))
```

... where `_` is the conventional name for the ignored argument, in this case a sequence.

We can get rid of it, simplifying to

```
(defn reductions [func & [init coll]] ... )
```

... and then to

```
(defn reductions [func init coll] ... )
```

... - a straightforward function of three arguments.

*Dealing with the underlying problems.*

Your function has two problems:

- slowness
- lack of laziness.

*Slowness*

The flashing red light in this function is the use of `last` in

```
(fn [acc item] (conj acc (func (last acc) item)))
```

This scans the whole of `acc` every time it is called, even if `acc` is a vector. So this `reductions` takes time proportional to the *square* of the length of `coll`: hopelessly slow for long sequences.

A simple fix is to replace `(last acc)` by `(acc (dec (count acc)))`, which takes effectively constant time.

*Lack of laziness*

We still can't lazily use what the function produces. For example, it would be nice to encapsulate the sequence of factorials like this:

```
(def factorials (reductions * 1N (next (range)))))
```

With your `reductions`, this definition never returns.

You have to entirely recast your function to make it lazy. Let's modify the standard -lazy -`reductions` to employ destructuring:

```
(defn reductions [f init coll]
  (cons
    init
    (lazy-seq
      (when-let [[x & xs] (seq coll)]
        (reductions f (f init x) xs)))))
```

Now we can define

```
(def factorials (reductions * 1N (next (range))))
```

Then, for example,

```
(take 10 factorials)
;(1N 1N 2N 6N 24N 120N 720N 5040N 40320N 362880N)
```

---

Another approach is to derive the sequence from itself, like a railway locomotive laying the track it travels on:

```
(defn reductions [f init coll]
  (let [answer (lazy-seq (reductions f init coll))]
    (cons init (map f answer coll))))
```

But this contains a hidden recursion (hidden from me, at least):

```
(nth (reductions * 1N (next (range))) 10000)
;StackOverflowError ...
```